# How database changes send to web client with node js?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, dashboard

I am developing web application with admin dashboard, I need to show notifications, new user register etc. on dashboard and I don't want to use a third party notification library like pusher, firebase etc. I am new to this, how normally this work?

I tried query every x seconds to see any new changes on server by http ajax request, but I realized this not the proper way and it may overload server handling. I am thinking to use websocket, then when server get new post request from other client, send message to dashboard, but I am not sure how to use websocket properly (when data changes how to send throuh socket)..

If websocket is not the ideal solution, how normally work this? Any tutorial or example on how to interact with ws object on server side would be much appreciated (if websocket is the ideal solution)

Comment: You are on the right track, websocket is the solution (eg socket.io). But I would recommend you not to get into coding it without reading documentation from start to finish. So you can understand about rooms, grouping, emiting etc etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, any tutorial or blog I can start reading?

Comment: I would recommend you starting with their documentation (https://socket.io/docs/) you will find plenty of examples, and demos on their site.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, I came up with a solution to my question. I hope it may helpful to others or I can improve my solution by getting some feedback from others or a better approach on my solution.

Just need two files to get this working

Client side (index.html)

```html
<p>
  open console to see what is happening.
</p>
<script>
  const socketProtocol = (window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss:' : 'ws:')
  const echoSocketUrl = socketProtocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':3000/notifications/'
  const socket = new WebSocket(echoSocketUrl);

  console.log('Waiting for new notifications from server');

  socket.onmessage = e => {
    console.log('Message from server:', event.data)
  }
</script>
```

Server side (server.js)

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const express = require('express')
var expressWs = require('express-ws');
var expressWs = expressWs(express());

var app = expressWs.app;

// express routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

app.get('/customers', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Showing list of customers');

  NotifyDashboard('someone viewed list of customers..');
})

// websocket route
app.ws('/notifications', (ws, req) => {
  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('WebSocket was closed')
  })
})

// Let all dashboard clients know.
function NotifyDashboard(data) {
  expressWs.getWss('/notifications').clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      client.send(data);
    }
  });
};

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log(`http/ws server listening on 3000`);
});
```